# Missing border lines in WPF DataGrid on Medium (125%) display

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a strange rendering issue with my wpf DataGrid on Win7 when the the display is set to Medium - 125%.The expected black vertical border line between the 2nd and 3rd column is not visible.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" >
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn  Width="150" ></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

This is the simplest code i can reproduce the problem with. You can use any viewmodel to see this problem.
Changing the Width from 150 to 150.1 for example fixes the problem. Can you guys explain to me what happens? How can I avoid this to happen?

Comment: Have you tried applying UseLayoutRounding or SnapToDevicePixels and see if it solves the problem? Using either of those will force WPF to line things up to the nearest pixel. I'm thinking the 125% setting causes some overlap in rendering perhaps.

Comment: I tried to apply on DataGrid and also setting in the style for DataGridCell. None of them helped.

Comment: Having the same issue. It appears that next column "eats" into the previous one and border is overlapped, so becomes invisible.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in discrepancy in how `DataGrid` calculates position and size of each column. Simple example: when you set `Width` of `DataGridColumn` to 95.0 the actual rendered with of column is 95.2; however, `DataGrid` will use 95.0 to calculate column X position, but not 95.2.

This discrepancy manifests itself in missing borders on some columns, as the next column "eats" by one pixel into space of the previous column due to missing fractional part.

[image]

The solution is to set correct `Width` for `DataGridColumn`, so it will be exactly the same as the rendered width. In this case `DataGrid` becomes aware of fractional part and all borders will be in place.

You can use the code below to calculate the width of column in "DPI aware" fashion before it is rendered. I don't claim credits for the code, as I got it from here https://habrahabr.ru/post/216833/.

```
var dpiProperty = typeof(SystemParameters).GetProperty("Dpi", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
var dpi = (int)dpiProperty.GetValue(null, null);
var pixelSize = 96.0 / dpi;

foreach (var dataGridColumn in this.DataGrid.Columns)
{
    var actualColumnWidth = dataGridColumn.Width.DisplayValue + (pixelSize / 2);
    var div = (actualColumnWidth * 1000) / (pixelSize * 1000);
    actualColumnWidth = (int)div * pixelSize;

    dataGridColumn.Width = new DataGridLength(actualColumnWidth, DataGridLengthUnitType.Pixel);
}
```