# Button Border clipped in WPF with 125% DPI Setting

Tags: wpf, dpi, groupbox, highdpi

When I use 125% DPI setting in Windows, sometimes a button border is not rendered. It seems to depend on the size and position, maybe also the parent element of a button:

[image]

In my app, I can also see in the WPF designer that a parent border seems to be too small in size, though the button itself is larger. Maybe the measure process is somehow wrong:

[image]

I tried changing UseLayoutRounding for the whole window, also changing SnapsToDevicePixels does not help.
DPI Awareness is set in the manifest.

Does anyone know how to fix this for the entire application?

Thats the code in a default Wpf Window Application (I can't reproduce the problem right now, but the problem persists in my application):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">

    <StackPanel>
        <GroupBox>
            <GroupBox.Header>
                <Button Width="20"
                        Height="22"
                        Content="X" />
            </GroupBox.Header>
        </GroupBox>

        <Button Width="20"
                Height="22"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Content="X" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: This works for me with 125% font size. What is your Operating System, Framework version?

Comment: Try to set DPI aware level for a process as described in the following post: [Setting the default DPI awareness for a process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/mt846517(v=vs.85))

Comment: @Jackdaw: Win10 1909, .NET Framework 4.7.1.
Can't reproduce it with the sample app at the moment, too. Only see the problem in the wpf designer.
But in my app, the problem persists. Our app already runs with dpiawareness turned on in the manifest.
But since the wpf designer already shows the problem, I think it is somewhere else ...

Comment: I can reproduce it and it has something to do with rounding up the pixels since there is no such thing as quarter pixel. Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33614402/missing-border-lines-in-wpf-datagrid-on-medium-125-display